# Create a MySQL login trigger with information_schema.processlist?

Tags: mysql, triggers

Is it possible to create a login trigger for MySQL? I'm trying to play with `processlist` table but it is not working:

```
use information_schema
CREATE TRIGGER test AFTER UPDATE ON information_schema.processlist FOR EACH ROW BEGIN END;
```

And it results in:

```
ERROR 1044 (42000): Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' to database 'information_schema'
```

What was the wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`INFORMATION_SCHEMA` tables are special, their content is actually generated on the fly whenever they are queried only. So you can't use DML or DDL queries on them.

To execute something on connect you can use the servers `init_connect` configuration variable, you have to be aware that for security reasons `init_connect` only works for non-SUPER users.

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_init_connect